# Calculate $\frac13+\frac29+\frac{1}{27}+\frac{2}{81}+\frac{1}{243}+\frac{2}{729}+\ldots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can we calculate the formula for the following series?

$\frac13+\frac29+\frac{1}{27}+\frac{2}{81}+\frac{1}{243}+\frac{2}{729}+\ldots$

I'm not quite sure what type of series it is anyway. It doesn't look geometric. Is there any strategy/procedure to follow in order to calculate the formula for a series of numbers?

Comment: Look at the sequence as made of two interwoven sequences, one going $1/3,1/27,1/243,...$ and the other going $2/9,2/81,2/729...$. Treat each separately using geometric series.

Comment: @coffeemath: same idea, two ways of looking at it :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are looking for the infinite sum, it is the sum of two geometric series:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{3^k}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{9^k}=\frac12+\frac18=\frac58
$$

Answer (score 10):

If we add neighbouring pairs, we get
$$\frac{5}{9}+\frac{5}{81}+\frac{5}{729}+\cdots.$$
This is an infinite geometric series with first term $\frac{5}{9}$ and common ratio $\frac{1}{9}$.

By the usual formula for the sum of an infinite geometric progression, the sum is 
$$\frac{5}{9}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{9}}.$$
This can be simplified to $\frac{5}{8}$.

Answer (score 6):

$$a_n=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{3^n}&,\;\;\text{if $\,n\,$ is odd}\\{}\\\frac{2}{3^n}&,\;\;\text{if $\,n\,$ is even}\end{cases}\;=\ldots\;$$